# Infowindow for each polygon in a layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Normally for a layer we can generate InfoWindow when onclick event raises. But here i have a number of polygons in a single layer. So, as by where condition in the query we can get each one and make styles diff for them. 
   But here  what i need is, for each polygon of a layer a InfoWndow has to be generate for onclick event.

Here my code for styling each polygon in a layer.

```
    var layer =  new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(
                                    {
                                         query: {
                                                    select: 'geometry',
                                                    from: 'myTableId'
                                                },
                                         styles: [  
                                                    {
                                                        where: "Dist_id in ('0101001') and Insert_date='25/08/2012'",
                                                        polygonOptions: {   strokeColor:"#0071bc",fillColor:"#0000FF",fillOpacity:0.2,strokeWeight:2,clickable:false }
                                                     },
                                                    {
                                                        where: "Dist_id in ('0101002') and Insert_date='25/08/2012'",
                                                        polygonOptions: {   strokeColor:"#0071bc",fillColor:"#FF0000",fillOpacity:0.2,strokeWeight:2,clickable:false }
                                                     },
                                                    {
                                                        where: "Dist_id in ('0101003') and Insert_date='25/08/2012'",
                                                        polygonOptions: {   strokeColor:"#0071bc",fillColor:"#00FF00",fillOpacity:0.2,strokeWeight:2,clickable:false }
                                                     },
                                                    {
                                                        where: "Dist_id in ('0101004') and Insert_date='25/08/2012'",
                                                        polygonOptions: {   strokeColor:"#0071bc",fillColor:"#FF00FF",fillOpacity:0.2,strokeWeight:2,clickable:false }
                                                     },
                                                    {
                                                        where: "Dist_id in ('0101005') and Insert_date='25/08/2012'",
                                                        polygonOptions: {   strokeColor:"#0071bc",fillColor:"#00FFFF",fillOpacity:0.2,strokeWeight:2,clickable:false }
                                                     }
                                                 ],
                                                 map:map                                              
                                    });
```

Now how can i generate InfoWindow for each polygon of a layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your polygons to be clickable, remove the "clickable: false" from the options.

Another option (which loses the benefit of FusionTablesLayer tile based rendering) is something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=37.174668&lng=-38.845970&zoom=2&type=m&tableid=1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ&tablequery=SELECT%20%20kml_4326%,%name%20FROM&where=name%20does%20not%20contain%20%27Antarctica%27) which uses the Fusion Tables API v1.0 to query the table and renders the polygons as native Google Maps API v3 polygons.

Comment: Dude here i need to generate infowindow by adding 'click' event listener for each polygon in the layer.

Comment: The only way to do that is to make them clickable.  You also can't do it with FusionTables (add click listeners to individual polygons), you need to add a click listener to the layer and use the information in the click event to detect the polygon.